# Error: While trying to resolve module @apollo/client React Native After trying many possible solutions out there, react native and apollo

Tags: react-native, apollo

[image: react native android]

Hello everyone,
i keep getting this error on the react native

- "react-native": "0.68.0",
- "@apollo/client": "^3.5.10",
- "react": "17.0.2",

after trying all possible solutions found online so far from :

1. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9194
2. [Error: While trying to resolve module @apollo/client React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338215/error-while-trying-to-resolve-module-apollo-client-react-native)

```
    metro.config file : 
    module.exports = {
     transformer: {
       getTransformOptions: async () => ({
         transform: {
           experimentalImportSupport: false,
           inlineRequires: true,
        },
      }),
    },
    resolver: {
      ...defaultResolver,
      sourceExts: [...defaultResolver.sourceExts, 'cjs'],
   },
   };
```

please any one has crossed this before?

Bests